# The orders of points in the function field of elliptic curves

Tags: arithmetic, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry, dedekind-domain, function-fields

Let $K$ be the function field of an elliptic curve $C$ over a finite field $\mathbb F_q$, and $|C|$  be the set of closed points of $C$, i.e. the set of places of $K$.

Let $A$ be any element of infinite order in the multiplicative group $(K^\times,\times)$, and hence $A=\dfrac{a}{b}$ for some $a,b\in\mathcal O_K$. So $A\in \mathfrak p$ for any prime ideal $\mathfrak p$ (corresponding to some closed point $p$) not dividing $(b)$. Therefore we can take the reduction of $A$ modulo $\mathfrak p$.

Here $$\mathcal O_K=\{x\in K||x|_\mathfrak p\leq 1\text{ for all }\mathfrak p\}.$$

My question is

Is the following set
$$ S=\{n\in\mathbb Z>0 \text{ s.t. there exists some }p\in |C| \text{ with the order of }A\text{ mod }\mathfrak p \text{ in } \mathcal O_K/\mathfrak p \text { is } n  \}$$
infinite?

In case $C$ is a projective line, i.e. $K=\mathbb F_q(t)$, It is not hard to show that the set $S$ is infinity by some elementary arguments.

In case $C$ is an elliptic curve, I do not know how to deal with this (and I do not know whether $S$ is finite or not).

This question is a global function field version of [Schinzel's theorem](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2152966?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents) for numberfields.

Comment: Why is $A=\frac{a}b$?  Note that $(a,b)$ is "given" by your elliptic curve $C$.

Comment: Edited. Here A is an element in $K^\times$. Thank you.

Comment: I am so sorry about that. Here I want $b$ to be a unit in $\mathcal O_\mathfrak p$, then $A\in \mathcal O_\mathfrak p$, where $\mathcal O_\mathfrak p$ is the ring of integers in $K$ corresponding to the place p.